# Get printable name of any QKeyEvent key value

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, keyboard-events

I'm using PyQt5.  When I write a keyPressEvent handler, I would like to be able to print, for debugging purposes, a human-readable description of what keys were pressed.  I want to be able to print such a thing no matter what, regardless of how many keys were pressed in the event, or whether they were modifiers or "regular" keys.

I have seen [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764138/get-the-name-of-a-key-from-qkeyevent-in-qt) in which the accepted answer (using C++) suggests creating a QKeySequence and using its `.toString` method.  I can do this like this:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    print("got a key event of ", QKeySequence(event.key()).toString())
```

However, this does not always work.  For instance, if I press the Shift key, it will result in an encoding error when I try to output (or if I try to encode it to UTF-8).  This seems to be because QKeySequence does not work on isolated modifier keys:

```
>>> QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Shift).toString().encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\u17c0\\udc20'
```

It gives gibberish instead of what I would expect, namely "Shift".  It works if I use `Qt.SHIFT` (sort of, in that it gives "Shift+"), but that is of no use, because `Qt.SHIFT` is not what I get in `event.key()` if I press the Shift key.

How can I get Qt to give me a printable representation of *anything* that might *ever* be the value of `event.key()`, where `event` is a QKeyEvent?

Comment: That's what the metaobject system is for - the [*other* answer to cited question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767101/1329652) is exactly what you need.

Comment: @KubaOber: It is not obvious to me how to adapt that code to Python.  Can you show how to do that In PyQt5?  I had a similar problem with the first half of the accepted answer; I cannot see how, in PyQt, to get access to the "reverse" mapping described, which in theory would map the numeric values of things like `Key_Shift` to their textual names.

Comment: I think you need to look into `Qt.ShiftModifier` and `Qt.ControlModifier` take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772595/how-to-check-if-a-key-modifier-is-pressed-shift-ctrl-alt

Comment: @ChristofferGøthgen: Those appear to be aliases for Qt.SHIFT and Qt.CTRL, which as I said are not useful because they are not present in the key value.  The starting point for me is the value of `event.key()`; I want to convert *that* into a string representation.  I know I could do it manually by checking all the modifiers from `event.modifiers()` and mapping them manually to strings, but what I want to know is if there is a way to get Qt to give it me without having to do all that myself.

Comment: Qt to give you anything? Why? It's Python, it's way simpler than in C++. The `Qt` object has `Key_foo` properties. It's trivial to enumerate them and find all that match. You can even pre-cache a reverse map of them for faster lookup. There's also the `Qt.KeyboardModifierMask`, etc. Forget about C++. Think Python. Python has ubiquitous introspection. If you know that there's an attribute of an object, you certainly can enumerate it, introspect it, etc. That's very, very different from C++. In C++, you need moc to introspect enums. In Python, it's in the language.

Comment: And modifiers certainly are in the key "code". The code in my answer works, after all. It's shorter in Python, and I encourage you to figure it out, keeping in mind that it's Python you're dealing with. And yes, you will have to write those meager 20-30 lines of code, Qt doesn't provide any ready-made way, unfortunately.

Comment: In any case, for `QKeySequence`, it looks like all you need to tweak is the modifier keys to modifiers conversion, i.e. map `Qt.Key_Shift` to `Qt.ShiftModifier`. There's a whooping six (6) of those.

Comment: There's a slim chance that PyQt folks mapped all of `Qt` object to dynamic attributes via `__getattr__`, and didn't implement `__dir__`, in which case of course no introspection will work - but even then, you need to deal with 6 special cases only. No biggie there.

Answer (score 15):

To deal with the specific question:

> How can I get Qt to give me a printable representation of anything
>   that might ever be the value of event.key(), where event is a
>   QKeyEvent?

The first things to note is that `event.key()` returns an `int`, rather than a `Qt.Key`. This is simply because the key can be *any unicode value whatsoever*. As a consequnce of this, it is not really feasible to give a printable representation of *literally anything*, since not every unicode key is printable, and it is impractical to enumerate them all.

The only API Qt provides for this is the `QKeySequnce` class. However, as you have found, it does not handle all inputs in the way you want. So you will have to roll your own solution.

It might be tempting to use `QMetaEnum` to convert key values to their names wherever possible. However, this won't work here, because there is no `staticMetaObject` for the `Qt` object, and PyQt does not provide anything like `qt_getQtMetaObject`. It also doesn't currently implement [`QMetaEnum.fromType`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaenum.html#fromType) (although this is likely to change in future versions).

So the only available solution is to use normal python introspection to build a mapping, and build up a printable representation from that.

Here is a basic demo (only tested on Linux):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

keymap = {}
for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
        keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

modmap = {
    Qt.ControlModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
    Qt.AltModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
    Qt.ShiftModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
    Qt.MetaModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
    Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
    Qt.KeypadModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
    }

def keyevent_to_string(event):
    sequence = []
    for modifier, text in modmap.items():
        if event.modifiers() & modifier:
            sequence.append(text)
    key = keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
    if key not in sequence:
        sequence.append(key)
    return '+'.join(sequence)

class Window(QWidget):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(keyevent_to_string(event))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @BrenBarn This is a very good answer... why hasn't been validated yet?